# Accessing the content of a specific td but unable to change its content

Tags: jquery, ajax

**EDIT**

```
<table class="table table-hover" id="patient_name_table">
                <tr id="after_tr_2">
                  <th>Patient</th>
                  <th>Phone</th>
                  <th>D.O.B</th>
                  <th>Address</th>
                  <th>Edit</th>
                </tr>
                <tbody>
                  <?php foreach($name_array as $tabName) { ?>
                  <tr id="<?php echo $tabName['id']; ?>">
                    <td class="nameid"><?php echo '<a href="patients.php?patient='.$tabName['id'].'">'.$tabName['patient_name'].'</a>';?></a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="phoneid"><?php echo $tabName['phone']?></td>
                    <td class="dobid"><?php echo $tabName['dob']?></td>
                    <td class="addressid"><?php echo $tabName['patient_address']?></td>
                    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="editInfo">Edit</button>
                  </tr>
                  <?php } ?>
                </tbody>
              </table>
```

And here is the update form:

```
<div class="box" id="dialog" title="Update Patient Informations" style="display:none">
                  <form class="form-horizontal" id="add_app_form">
                    <table class="table table-striped table-hover" style="width:650px;">
                        <tr><th style="text-align:left;width:150px">Patient Name:</th> <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="name_upd"></td></tr>
                        <tr><th style="text-align:left;width:150px">Phone:</th> <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone_upd"></td></tr>
                        <tr><th style="text-align:left;width:150px">D.O.B:</th><td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="dob_upd"></td></tr>
                        <tr><th style="text-align:left;width:150px">Address:</th> <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="address_upd"></td></tr>
                    <tr><td colspan="3"><button type="button" id="upd_info" class="btn btn-info pull-right">Update</button></td></tr>
                    <table>
                </form>
              </div>
```

I have this line where I get the ID of a specific row in my table:

```
var id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
```

Now, I need to get a specific info from this `tr`, and from the name `td` that have a `class=nameid`, using this line:

```
var x = $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').children('td.nameid').text();
```

Now the problem is that I can't access `x` to change the value of it into a new one inside a success function of AJAX call.

Here is the ajax call:

```
$("#upd_info").on('click', function()
      {
        var upd_name = $("#name_upd").val();
        var upd_dob = $("#dob_upd").val();
        var upd_phone = $("#phone_upd").val();
        var upd_address = $("#address_upd").val();
        $.ajax({
          url: 'upd_patient.php',
          data: {upd_id: id, n: upd_name, d: upd_dob, p:upd_phone, a:upd_address},
          type: 'POST',
          dataType: 'JSON',

          success:function(res3)
          {
            $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "close" );
            //here I need to access td of class nameid and change the value
          },
          error:function(res3)
          {
            console.log("Error Updating info");
          }
        });
```

Is their a way for it ?

Answer (score 0):

Text will return to you the text from inside it, not the accessor to the text. Try leaving x as `$(this).parent('td').parent('tr').children('td.nameid')`, and getting the text with `x.text()`, and then setting it with `x.text('new text')`

Answer (score 0):

`success` callback has own `this`. You should get the reference of `.nameid` before the ajax call and change the text in `success` like following.

```
$("#upd_info").on('click', function(){
    var upd_name = $("#name_upd").val();
    var upd_dob = $("#dob_upd").val();
    var upd_phone = $("#phone_upd").val();
    var upd_address = $("#address_upd").val();

    //added following line
    var x = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.nameid');

    $.ajax({
        url: 'upd_patient.php',
        data: { upd_id: id, n: upd_name, d: upd_dob, p: upd_phone, a: upd_address },
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',

        success: function(res3) {
            $("#dialog").dialog("close");

            //added following line
            x.text('changed text'); 
        },
        error: function(res3) {
            console.log("Error Updating info");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Are your elements dynamically generated? @androidnation

Comment: Yeah the table is generated with PHP where it get values from db and each row have a specific ID

Comment: Try `$(document).on('click', '#upd_info', function () {` instead of `$("#upd_info").on('click', function(){`. @androidnation

Comment: If I can select another time the row that I originally updated using $("+id+")... I could find the proper solution that I want

Comment: Yeap I will add it in seconds

Comment: You are duplicating the id `editInfo`. Can you show click event of  `#editInfo`. @androidnation